# C# analogue to java stream operations

Tags: java, c#

I have a following sample in Java that I need to rewrite in C#:

```
Map<string, Human> humansMap = humans.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        this::extractHumanId,
        human => idToHuman.get(human.getPassportId());
```

`humans.stream()` - gets a sequence of elements from humans collection

`.collect(Collector)` - collects data from the stream to a new collection.
`toMap` in Java produces `Map` (`IDictionary` in C#)

`this::extractHumanId` - invoking a method from this class

`human => idToHuman.get` - lambda expression, the element that is iterating now will be used here

How do I rewrite in in C#?

Comment: Something like `Dictionary<string, Human> humansMap = humans.ToDictionary(human => human.HumanId, human => idToHuman[human.PassportId]);`? Depending on `humans` collection you may want to add `AsEnumerable()` or `OfType<Human>()`

Comment: Please post your Java code using valid syntax (hint: try to match up your open and closing parentheses).

Comment: Try searching google for LINQ.